# How can I "fix" a user that has no home dir but is logged in

Tags: linux, user-management, home-directory

I created `postgres` using the `useradd` command without thinking twice about it. I've already got postgres installed and running. I'm unable to add a home directory to `postgres` because the user is currently logged in.

Can I somehow log the `postgres` user out and remove it? If I delete the user (and recreate it using `adduser`), will all of its files still belong to it (assuming same UID)? Are there other potential problems? If this won't work, can I at least log the user out so that I can set its home directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- No need to delete the account, better *modify* it to keep UID/GID of the files in sync with existing files.
- Stop the database server if it is running, that is the reason that it appears to be "logged in".
- Modify the home directory of the user using `usermod(8)`, look in the manpage for the `-d` switch.
- Start the server.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is that I can't `usermod -d /home/postgres postgres` because `postgres` is currently logged in. How do I remedy that?

Comment: I already told you how. Stop the database server. If that is not enough, `kill` the remaining processes of the postgres user

Comment: It wasn't enough - I had to log the user out (or as you say, kill the remaining processes). However, even after making `/home/postgres/` (with the contents of `/etc/skel/`) the home directory and giving `postgres` recursive ownership, `su`-ing as `postgres` still resulted in a `$` command prompt (using `/bin/sh` vs `/bin/bash`)... so I nuked the entire server from orbit, and in the past hour I've set up an entirely new server, this time remembering to use `adduser postgres`.